# Android, set JCIFS log level

Tags: android, jcifs

From the web, I have seen two answers. One is setting `-Djcifs.util.loglevel=3` and another is calling `jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.util.loglevel", "3")`.

I do not know how to do the former one in Android Studio, so I did the latter one. But I see no addditional logs (or any difference), so I am not sure whether it worked or not.

1. Is it possible to use the former method in Android?
2. How can I know the log level is correctly set? Any way to confirm that additional log is coming from JCIFS?

Android SDK 25 (7.1.1 Nougat) and JCIFS 1.3.17.

Answer (score 1):

I looked into its source code. It was checking LogStream.level. So, I did the following, and it started printing debug messages.

```
LogStream.setLevel(10);
```

Why didn't the methods that the web sites showed work?